# How could I test update method use Junit

Tags: java, junit

```
public boolean changePassword(User user, String newpass) {
    user.setPasswordHash(newpass);
    if(update(user) == false)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public boolean update(User user){
   SqlSession session = factory.openSession()
   try {
         UserMapper mapper = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
            mapper.update(user);
            session.commit();
            return  true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

now this is one of my test.it is when change Pasword Success.

```
  @Test
public void shouldChangeUserPasswordWhenAsked() {
    User  updatedUser = new User();
    updatedUser.setUserName("user");
    updatedUser.setPasswordHash("newpassword");
    when(userMapper.findByUsername("user")).thenReturn(updatedUser);

    Boolean updateResult = userService.password(user,"newpassword");
    verify(userMapper).update(user);
    assertEquals("updatedUserSuccess",userService.getByUsername(user.getUserName()).getPasswordHash(),"newpassword");
    assertEquals("updatedSuccess",updateResult,true);
}
```

now how I want to test the failed situation,how can I do it? should I change my update method? before test I mock dabase and some method rely on database like this

```
 @Before
public void setup(){
    session = mock(SqlSession.class);
    userMapper = mock(UserMapper.class);
    userRoleMapper = mock(UserRoleMapper.class);

    sessionFactory = mock(SqlSessionFactory.class);

    when(sessionFactory.openSession()).thenReturn(session);
    when(session.getMapper(UserMapper.class)).thenReturn(userMapper);
    when(session.getMapper(UserRoleMapper.class)).thenReturn(userRoleMapper);

    userService = new UserServiceImpl(sessionFactory);

    user = new User();
    user.setUserName("user");
    user.setPasswordHash("password");
}
```

Comment: I would not change the production code to get a test to run...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell one of your mocks to throw an exception when called:

```
when(userRoleMapper.update(user)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("test exception"));
```

Or, if the `update()` method returns `void`:

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException("test exception")).when(userRoleMapper).update(user);
```

Mockito has a [very good documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html). Read it.

Note that catching Exception is an extremely bad practice, and that your method should probably let exceptions bubble instead of catching them and returning false.